# Draw a snowflake with Frozen on Code.org

Tags: logo-lang

I'm trying to solve [this problem](http://studio.code.org/s/frozen/stage/1/puzzle/11) which asks to make a snowflake, so far I tried using *forward by 100 pixels* and *right by 90 degrees* but I only made it do a shape in the left bottom corner, then I did a square and it said I messed up...

Could somebody give a hint on what I should do?

Here's a screenshot of the problem with my solution so far :

[image: The problem with my solution so far]

*PS: this is my dad's account.*

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with JavaScript. I can only advice you to read the description again: *"Let's create a new snowflake by using the “Repeat" block to repeat a parallelogram 4 times, turning right by 90 degrees between each parallelogram"*. The parallelogram is already built for you. All you have to do is add the repeat block and adjust the "turn right" value.

Comment: Ok, changed tag. Unfortunately, there's no tag for "novice" or "learning"

Comment: On your solution, please click on *Show code* in the top right corner and edit in the Javascript code into your question.

Comment: FWIW, this has less to do with programming, and more with understanding and applying the instructions.

Comment: @Felix True...that is how most programming tutorials work, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to draw 4 parallelograms and each parallelogram is constructed by 4 lines.
The code below draws two line twice (= 4 lines) then rotates 90 degrees and repeats all this 4 times.

[image: Snowflake]

Comment: Now that you got the solution try to understand how and why it works to learn something from it.